Who will the house be cleaned (by) from now on?
Should I say

Who will the house be cleaned from now on?

OR

Who will the house be cleaned by from now on?

The first sentence is written on my English book. Is the second sentence wrong?
I know the best sentence is

Who will clean the house from now on?

But we're learning passive voice in school. I have a test in three days, please help.

The first sentence is very bad English, so please check if that is exactly what is printed. The second and third are OK, and equally so.

What "English book" is it?

In very formal, antiquated,  English it would be "By whom will the house be cleaned?"

The book is an English workbook based on my school textbook. It's popular when preparing for school English exams so I didn't think there would be an error in it!
